How to solve this binomial summation?
I was solving my problem sheet and came upon this problem. original problem
I deduced the problem to this form, but I can't solve further. Can you please provide some help.
$$\sum_{r=0}^{12}\binom{13}{r}\binom{13}{r+1}$$
I tried to solve this sum by expanding the binomial coefficients inside the summation but I wasn't able to get to any conclusion.
I also thought to multiply two binomaials, but to no avail.
I was able to eliminate the options and get the answer from the original question. But I want to deduce an appropriate and proper solution to this summation.
Any insights or hint to help me solve this problem is much appreciated.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Is it better now @AnotherUser

A series is an infinite sum. That's simply a sum.

Take a look at https://oeis.org/A001791

Your sum, $$\sum_{r=0}^{12}\binom{13}{r}\binom{13}{r+1}$$ evaluates to $9657700$.
We can get this answer using WolframAlpha or using Pascal's triangle. If you want to solve it by hand then you'll find out it's equal to $26 \choose 12$ or $26 \choose 14$.
You should clarify that the sum is not equal to $a+b$, it's equal to $ab$, so $ab = 9657700$. This isn't an answer, just a hint. Hope this helps :)

Can you explain a bit further? I can't understand what are you trying to say. Also, Is there a short method to solve this sum without manual labour of finding each and every value.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208043/evaluate-the-sum-sum-k-1n-n-choose-k-1-n-choose-k
